# After setting chmod -R 0700 still current user can see and edit the files

Tags: server, permissions, chmod

I have a folder in my server I am setting this folder rights by

```
sudo chmod -R 0700 myfolder
```

when i print rights with ls -l everything is fine nobody has any right except root but i can open the file and even edit with the current user im signed in as .

why the rights doesnt work proper according to chmod i am suposed not to be able to do anything with the contents of the folder

id user and ls -ld folder output i am sharing below

[image]

Comment: Whats the output of `id "$USER"` ? also `ls -ld myfolder` ?

Comment: @heemayl i am updating the question

Comment: As you can see the directory (and possibly all the files inside) is owned by user `nikos`, not `root`..so as you are `nikos` you would be able to `rwx`..to change the ownership to `root` you need `sudo chown -R root node` ..then everything should be all right..

Comment: i see so even if i dont allow myself to read write anyway as the owner i am able

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the output of `ls -ld node` suggests the `node` directory is owned by user `nikos` (and group `nikos`), not by `root` with a permission of `700`. As a result being user `nikos` you you have read, write, execute permission in that directory.

Also note that `sudo chmod -R 0700 myfolder` does not change the ownership to `root`, it simply sets the permission bits as `0700` as user `root`. If you are the owner of that directory you could do it by `chmod -R 0700 myfolder`, no need for `sudo`.

There is a catch though, as we are doing it recursively `-R`, you need to have the files under `myfolder` directory owned by you to change their permissions. Otherwise the original permissions of those files will prevail.

Now if you want to make `root` as the owner of that directory and files under it (recursively):

```
sudo chown -R root node
```

If you want to make the owner group as group `root` too :

```
sudo chown -R root:root node
```